# Storing records of slightly dissimilar types in a RDBMS

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, data-modeling

I know SQL, but I'm not terribly experienced with it. I have a system in which I would like to log user logins, logouts and other security-related events in an indexed database to be able to pose manual queries to it, and I figure some SQL-based RDBMS should be the best fit for the job.

However, the records I'd like to store have similar, but not identical, data. All records would store a timestamp and a username, but the other data items would differ. For instance:

- A login event would store the IP address the user logged in from, along with an ID for the created session.
- A logout event would store the session ID but not the IP address (since I don't have access to the IP address at the point of logout).
- An email-change event would store former and new e-mail address of the user.

How should one model something like this in a relational database? I can imagine at least three possibilities:

- Use different tables for each kind of data item
- Add columns for all the different data items and leave them as `NULL` for records that don't use them
- Use one central table with the common data items, and auxiliary tables that store the rest of the data, linking to an event ID in the central table

Clearly, each one has its own advantages and disadvantages. I do realize that this is a somewhat subjective question and is also likely to depend on actual use-cases, but I imagine there ought to be standard/best practices for this kind of thing that I just haven't seen. Are any of my suggestions reasonable or standard? Is there some other option that I have missed that is better?

Comment: The design of a database should be based on how the data is going to be used, not on how it is generated (although that can inform various options).  Your question doesn't say how the data is being used, so there is really no basis for intelligent design decisions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I did write that I intend to use it for manual queries only. I know that is a vague description, and that's because I don't know exactly the kind of queries I'm going to ask it. :) My basic intent is to use it for forensics in security events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions you mention appear in Martin Fowler's book [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html). You might like to read that book to see what he says about using these patterns.

> Use different tables for each kind of data item

- [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/concreteTableInheritance.html)

> Add columns for all the different data items and leave them as NULL for records that don't use them

- [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)

> Use one central table with the common data items, and auxiliary tables that store the rest of the data, linking to an event ID in the central table

- [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)

Fowler also covers a fourth solution for this problem:

- [Serialized LOB](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serializedLOB.html)

Comment: Haha, I'm kind of happy that I managed to think of what seems to be precisely the three common solutions to this problem. :) While I'm not going to buy a book just for this, the names alone of these patterns provided me with a lot of search terms to google for, leading to pages that describe various aspects and implications of them. Thanks for that!